# Oracle throws Not a group by expression

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query, where I use a table which right joins a date table, what means that I get all date values. I only want to have the values between the borders of my table result set. I have following query

```
Select DD.CAL_YEAR, DD.WEEK_OF_YEAR, Count(Distinct FPP.ID) As Total
From FACT_PAY_PAYMENT FPP
    Right Join DIM_DATE DD On FPP.REQUESTED_EXECUTION_DATE_ID = DD.ID
Group By DD.CAL_YEAR, DD.WEEK_OF_YEAR
Having DD.ID >= MIN(FPP.REQUESTED_EXECUTION_DATE_ID)
   AND DD.ID <= MAX(FPP.REQUESTED_EXECUTION_DATE_ID);
```

But when I execute this, I get following error from Oracle

> Error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
>
> SQLState:  42000 ErrorCode: 979

What is wrong in my query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your query the problem is the last statement (`having`):

```
Select DD.CAL_YEAR, DD.WEEK_OF_YEAR, Count(Distinct FPP.ID) As Total
    From FACT_PAY_PAYMENT FPP
    Right Join DIM_DATE DD On FPP.REQUESTED_EXECUTION_DATE_ID = DD.ID
    Group By DD.CAL_YEAR,DD.WEEK_OF_YEAR
--->        Having DD.ID >= MIN(FPP.REQUESTED_EXECUTION_DATE_ID) AND DD.ID <= MAX(FPP.REQUESTED_EXECUTION_DATE_ID)
```

Indeed, having should also be applied on a field included in the `group by`, and it's **not** the case of `DD.ID`. 
So Oracle complains with a (now clearer) message "*(DD.ID is) `not` (in) `a group by expression`*"

A possible solution, if compatible with your business logic, could be transforming your `having` clause to a simple `where` clause:

```
Select DD.CAL_YEAR, DD.WEEK_OF_YEAR, Count(Distinct FPP.ID) As Total
    From FACT_PAY_PAYMENT FPP
    Right Join DIM_DATE DD On FPP.REQUESTED_EXECUTION_DATE_ID = DD.ID
    Where DD.ID >= ... 
    And DD.ID <= ...
    Group By DD.CAL_YEAR,DD.WEEK_OF_YEAR
```

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) you can find a nice explication of `having` vs `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want *all* the date values between the min and max, even those with no matching values.  I am guessing that the aggregation by year and week of year is getting only a handful of ids from `DD`.  So, one approach is:

```
Select DD.CAL_YEAR, DD.WEEK_OF_YEAR, Count(Distinct FPP.ID) As Total
From DIM_DATE DD LEFT JOIN
     FACT_PAY_PAYMENT FPP
     On FPP.REQUESTED_EXECUTION_DATE_ID = DD.ID
Group By DD.CAL_YEAR, DD.WEEK_OF_YEAR
Having MAX(DD.ID) >= MIN(FPP.REQUESTED_EXECUTION_DATE_ID) AND
       MIN(DD.ID) <= MAX(FPP.REQUESTED_EXECUTION_DATE_ID);
```

However, doing this filtering in the `HAVING` clause is a waste of effort -- the query has already aggregated everything.  Here is a way to get it in a `WHERE`:

```
Select DD.CAL_YEAR, DD.WEEK_OF_YEAR, Count(Distinct FPP.ID) As Total
From DIM_DATE DD LEFT JOIN
     FACT_PAY_PAYMENT FPP
     On FPP.REQUESTED_EXECUTION_DATE_ID = DD.ID CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT MIN(FPP.REQUESTED_EXECUTION_DATE_ID) as minredi,
             MAX(FPP.REQUESTED_EXECUTION_DATE_ID) as maxredi
      FROM FACT_PAY_PAYMENT
     ) minmax
Where DD.ID >= minmax.minredi AND DD.ID <= minmax.maxredi
Group By DD.CAL_YEAR, DD.WEEK_OF_YEAR;
```